# A command to troubleshoot UDP traffic forwarding issues?

Tags: udp, forwarding

I've been setting up a UDP forwarding configuration to a load balancer in a private network in Azure with a colleague. The attempted setup was something like this:

- There's the actual target UDP server running in `172.16.2.2:5075`
- The UDP load balancer is running in `172.16.1.1:5050`

So we created a simple forwarding rule from the load balancer with such a mapping.

However, the target server didn't log any traffic hitting it. So I tried troubleshooting the issue. Using a Ubuntu VM running in the same network, I checked that the load balancer responded to UDP traffic by running

```
nc -zvu 172.16.1.1 5050
```

which reported a success. However, `172.16.2.2` didn’t seem to receive anything.

So I tested the target machine directly (with `nc -zvu 172.16.2.2 5075`) and it logged a call being received.

I couldn’t find any option in e.g. `nc` to follow UDP forwarding/redirects etc. So to see where the traffic was dropped, I also tried running e.g. `tracepath -4 -p 5050 172.16.1.1` but only saw a list of "no reply" lines.

My colleague actually managed to solve this particular problem (by changing the forwarding rule from a load-balancing rule to an inbound NAT rule in Azure) so I don't need help with that anymore.

But for learning purposes and solving future problems, I would love to hear how I could troubleshoot such issues. Is there a command (preferably one found on e.g. Ubuntu distro by default) or a combination of commands to see what fails in a load balancer’s forwarding rule like this and where?

Even if the issue in this case was more or less Azure-specific, I'd be more interested in finding **a cloud-agnostic way to at least see how far a UDP traffic forwarding chain works**. The more details it could give about the possible reasons for not reaching the final destination, the better.

*Edit:*

Modified the title and text a bit to make it clearer I'm looking for a (built-in) command to use and not e.g. proprietary software for this.

Comment: I'd also appreciate it if your possible downvote comes with some feedback so I can improve the question.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I have expressed myself poorly in the question then, as I was mainly interested in a command (preferably one found on e.g. Ubuntu distro by default) I could use for this. I added the word "command" in the title yesterday already as I kinda suspected this, but I'll see if I can make it clearer still.